# Quaternion from 6 vectors (rotating one coordinate system into another)

Tags: c++, vector, quaternions, coordinate-systems

I have 6 unit vectors (representing the X/Y/Z axis) of 2 arbitrary coordinate systems. The vector values of the second coordinate system are based on the first system. I need to rotate one system into the other and return the matching quaternion. What would be the most reasonable way to do this in c++?

There are a number of posts on SO talking about converting y-up/z-up/left-/right-handed systems into each other, unfortunately I need this to be a generic solution for any 6 unit vectors. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: `What would be the most reasonable way to do this in c++?` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles, obviously

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux not an option, i need a quaternion returned and fought with gimbal lock before using Euler angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 orthogonal vectors it is probably rotation matrix 3x3. You can build 2 matrices and find relative rotation as r_relative = r1.transpose() * r2;

Than convert matrix to quaternion using any tested lib.

Or convert both rotations to quaternion and

q_relative = q1.inverted() * q2;

Comment: thanks! since this is for motion tracking and bone orientation, i found this paper yesterday which basically confirms what you recommend, with the added info of relating my current bone orientation to the one before in the hierarchy. [link](http://publicationslist.org/data/melslater/ref-266/p175-spanlang.pdf) under 3.1, second column